# real time plotting on iPhone using core plot?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I want to use core-plot for drawing line graph dynamically. data won't come at a time, we will be receiving point by point dynamically.

Is it possible to draw the chart dynamically using core-plot i.e drawing point by point as on when we receive the (x,y) point?

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: Hey Brad. Thanks for your comments. Could you please  suggest a more recent tutorial ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a tutorial (in french) but code is in english : http://www.geckogeek.fr/installer-et-utiliser-coreplot-sur-iphone-ipad.html

Comment: Merci beaucoup, c'est encore plus simple comme ça :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can do this reasonably easily.  For each received data point, append it to an array of values to display.  As these data points come in, call `-reloadData` on the Core Plot graph (or just the particular plot) to redraw the graph, passing in the array you just added a value to in response to the `-numbersForPlot:field:recordIndexRange:` delegate method.

If you need to adjust the plot range to track your data points (for a moving ticker), recalculate the new CPPlotRange for the X axis and set the plot space's `xRange` property to that.

Use the [CPTestApp-iPhone](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/tree/master/examples/CPTTestApp-iPhone), [AAPLot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/tree/master/examples/AAPLot), or [StockPlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/tree/master/examples/StockPlot) examples as templates for how to set up the line chart overall, and modify from that starting point.

I do something similar to this on the Mac in a scientific application:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sunsetlakesoftware.com](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/SensingInAirAgain.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thanks Brad.
I would like to ask you one more help on this. How to implement the ZoomIn and ZoomOut for Core-plot? It would be great if you provide some example.
Please help me.

Comment: @ram007: There is no native support for pinch-zooming at the moment.  You could place the graph within a UIScrollView, and then rescale the graph extents in response to changes in the scroll view zoom scale, but that would also zoom the axes during a pinch event.  Unfortunately, the best way would be to add this capability to the framework by modifying CPResponder to handle multitouch gestures, and that would take some work.

Comment: @BradLarson How do you do a live graph if you don't know that min and max to being with?  How does the graph create the scale?

Comment: @Nic - You adjust the scale as needed when you add points.  If you wish to maintain a fixed Y height, you can do that, or you can scale it based on new values that you've appended.  Similarly, the X scale can move with your incoming samples.  It's up to you to decide how to adjust the graph based on new data.

Comment: @BradLarson, how i received audio byte while audio file plying playing and depends on strength of sound i want to draw graph?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you could make use of a demo project I put together and wrote about [here](http://memention.com/blog/2009/08/20/How-hard-can-it-be.html) (not core plot related though).

It draws a *EKG* graph but should easily be modified to use another input than the repeated "heart beat"...See line 320 in [EAGLView.m](http://github.com/epatel/EKG/blob/master/Classes/EAGLView.m#L320) where the indata is entered into the array.