# live graph and iPad app

Tags: javascript, ipad, core-plot

i currently have highcharts realtime graph working on a browser (e.g. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update ), but we now want to an iphone/ipad app so that the users dont have to go and type in the address (instead open an app) and they see the live graph.

is there an easy way to convert the existing webpage (with highcharts.js and jquery. js into an app?) i looked at [real time plotting on iPhone using core plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2399836/572059) but looks a bit complex for me (i dont have any prev knowledge on building apps )
Also, http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=94 indicates there is a known problem with core-plot dynamically updating the data in real time. any live examples would be of great help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to create a [iOS web-application](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html), so you can use Highcharts JS like in a normal webpage. The Highcharts homepage says it's compatible with iPhone/iPad.

Web-apps can be designed to look like native apps and can also be started directly from the homescreen without typing the URL.

Comment: looked at the examples? http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code but how do i package all that into an app (do i have to do that in xcode or dashcode?)? any examples/instructions plz..

Comment: Is there any sample application or Tutorial available for this ?So that i can learn how to integrate Highchart in my iPad application.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/), on [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com/) you can upload your web-assets and download a ready compiled (web-)app wich will run as a regular app on your device.

For a simple web-app tested on android this worked great (but do not count on anything outside the browser being available to you (phonebook/sms etc)).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very late, but [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/paul-delange/5253394) that embeds HighCharts into a UIWebView. Embed jQuery (I used jquery-1.9.1.min.js) and the HighCharts .js files in the app bundle and this will load them into the web view.