# How to display live core plot graph in iPad?

Tags: ipad, dynamic, graph, live, core-plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [real time plotting on iPhone using core plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399836/real-time-plotting-on-iphone-using-core-plot)

I want to display live core plot graph in iPad like ECG live graph.If anyone know examples or sample code or any idea.please tell me...