# how to implement and show Sound Amplitude graphically on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, voice-recording

The task is to show amplitude of the voice spoken into the Mic of the phone and show the amplitude like this:

[image]

Can someone please guide me how can i achieve this.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is not so easy..

you can check:

- for the "animated wave graph" you can check Apple example "[aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)"
- for handling audio you can check also "[SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html)"

Answer (score 1):

Look into Core Graphics and drawRect.

Helped you search:

[How do I draw a line on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856354/how-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be done only by core plot framework.. you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402899/919545) at Brad larson's answer.