# Play a song and show the waves

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming, avcapturedevice

I have been working in AVAudioPlayer and I would like to draw a wave form which looks look like this:

[image]

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/waveform

Answer (score 1):

Following project source code can help you:

https://github.com/ioslovers/ATTabandHoldAudioRecord

Other than this, apple provides this sample code: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

Other same stack overflow replays which is showing real time ploting: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402899/905514